# Notice: Undefined index: HTTPS even when running on HTTPS

Tags: php, ssl, https, undefined

Centos 6.5
Plesk 11.5
PHP 5.3.3

I have installed a SSL sertificate on a website and it looks like its running like it should (chrome, firefox etc.. accepts is with a green lock).

Now, my problem is that $_SERVER['HTTPS'] is empty/false.

I get messages like: Undefined index: HTTPS in ...

Does anybody have any clue why HTTPS is not being set?

Comment: Oh cool, no code. Let's guess what your code is.

Comment: On a more serious note: All webservers set the HTTPS flag, if correctly configured. So either your code has some kind of spelling mistakes or modifies the superglobal or the webserver is misconfigured.

Comment: dump your `$_SERVER` and look for Alternatives

Comment: Who makes the SSL load off?

Comment: have seen this happen with load balances\proxies

Comment: $_SERVER dump:
http://pastebin.com/91pgpyZ6

The code is simple:
var_dump($_SERVER['HTTPS']);

SSL from:
https://www.sslforfree.com/

Comment: @Jay Blanchard its not a duplicate. I think i figured it out now. Looks like its bacause i use DNS trough Cloudflare.

Comment: You set CF up to use Flex SSL and not Full SSL. The request from the visitor to CF **does** use SSL, but the request from CF to your server (origin server) is plain HTTP.